# Axis error (FileNotFoundException: access is denied)

Tags: axis

I am new with axis and servers so i have no idea why i am getting this result. I am getting this result when trying to access
http://localhost:8080/axis/HelloWorld.jws?wsdl

> AXIS error

Sorry, something seems to have gone wrong... here are the details:

Fault - ; nested exception is:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Nick\Dropbox\SENG3400A2\tomcat\webapps\axis\HelloWorld.jws (Access is denied)

web.xml is the default tomcat xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
  <description>
     Welcome to Tomcat
  </description>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Please post your `web.xml` file and tell us the exact name of your WAR file.

Comment: sample.war is the name of the WAR

Comment: Thanks for updating.  Your `web.xml` file seems to indicate that you don't even have a servlet deployed at the moment.  If you did have a servlet called `HelloWorld`, then you would access it using something like this: `http://localhost:8080/sample/HelloWorld`

Comment: So when i navigate to  http://localhost:8080/axis/HelloWorld.jws is says : - There is a Web Service here
Click to see the WSDL. then i get the above error.